# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setMed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x746dda0'

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am making an app that will help people with certain health conditions manage their medication. I have created a modal to add medication which works and saves the new medication using core data.

I am now trying to allow people to edit their medication after it has been saved. To do this I am trying to send a managed object of the medication to a "fibromappMedsEditViewController" and assign the information in the viewDidLoad method of the class.

I keep getting this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setMed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x746dda0'
```

Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

**relevant methods in fibromappMedsListViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   //selMed declared at top of file as NSManagedObject *selMed;
    selMed = [self.meds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"SELECTED MED: %@",[selMed valueForKey:@"name"] );
    UIStoryboardSegue *segueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"editMeds"];

    NSLog(@"%@",segueString);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editMeds" sender:indexPath];

}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


    NSLog(@"%@",segue.destinationViewController);

    NSLog(@"%@",[selMed valueForKey:@"name"] );

    fibroMappMedsEditViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
    dest.med = selMed;


}
```

**The fibroMappMedsEditViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface fibroMappMedsEditViewController : UITableViewController
- (IBAction)saveChanges:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)deleteBtnPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)dosageChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)maxDosageChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)typeChanged:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tbName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tbDose;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tbMaxDose;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tbType;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *stepperDose;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *stepperMaxDose;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *changeMeasure;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObject *med;

@end
```

**The fibroMappMedsEditViewController.m - just the parts I altered that affect the way the controller loads**

```
#import "fibroMappMedsEditViewController.h"
#import "fibroMappAppDelegate.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface fibroMappMedsEditViewController ()

@end

@implementation fibroMappMedsEditViewController


@synthesize tbName;
@synthesize tbDose;
@synthesize tbMaxDose;
@synthesize tbType;
@synthesize med;
double dose;
double maxDose;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tbName.text = [med valueForKey:@"name"];//name is a string in the model
    tbDose.text = [med valueForKey:@"dose"];//dose is a double in the model
    tbMaxDose.text = [med valueForKey:@"maxDose"];//maxDose is a double in the model
    tbType.text = [med valueForKey:@"type"];//type is a string in the model

}
```

If you need to see anything else please just ask.

Also, I am using storyboards for this app.

Comment: What does this show?  NSLog(@"%@",segue.destinationViewController);

Comment: <UINavigationController: 0x746dda0>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears from that log, that your fibroMappMedsEditViewController (which should start with a capital letter BTW) is embedded in a navigation controller. You need to get to that navigation controller's root view controller.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;
    fibroMappMedsEditViewController *dest = (fibroMappMedsEditViewController *)nav.topViewController;
    dest.med = selMed;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it doesnt crash now but it does give me a warning: " Incompatible pointer types initializing 'fibroMappMedsEditViewController *__strong' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'"

also for some reason it doesnt display the values from med in the modal's text boxes :/

Comment: @JamieMcAllister, it just needs a cast to fix that warning. I've updated my answer to show that. As for the other problem, if you log self.med in viewDidLoad, what does that give you?

Comment: @JamieMcAllister, if you log selMed in prepareForSegue what does it give?

Comment: <NSManagedObject: 0x742e200> (entity: Medication; id: 0x742d4d0 <x-coredata://7B23EF92-14E3-4F5F-9EEB-E422C78821A1/Medication/p1> ; data: {
    dose = 1;
    lastTaken = nil;
    maxDose = 1;
    name = testt;
    type = Mililitres;
})

     that information if correct

Comment: do you have any ideas??

Comment: @JamieMcAllister, I don't have a lot of experience with this, but I think you need to pass the managedObjectContext, not the managed object. However, depending on what you're doing with the information in the detail controller, you might create an NSDictionary of all the managed object's properties (from selMed) in prepareForSegue, and pass that dictionary instead.